# Error al registar los datos en una base de datos mySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo en esto de PHP y mySQL. El problema es, que aparece error cuando quiero ingresar datos desde un formulario a una base de datos, no me da errores de sintaxis pero he aquí el codigo, espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdformulario");
    if (!$conexion) {
echo "Error al conectar a la base de datos";
                    }
    else {
echo "Conectado a la base de datos con exito";
        }


$nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
$correo=$_POST['Correo'];
$apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
$fecha_nac=$_POST['Fecha'];
$banco=$_POST["Metodo"];
$Numero=$_POST["Numero"];
$codigocvc=$_POST["Codigo"];
$fechav=$_POST["Fechav"];
$codigop=$_POST["Codigop"];
$envio=$_POST["Metodoe"];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO productos VALUES('$nombre','$correo','$apellido','$fecha_nac','$banco','$Numero','$codigocvc','$fechav','$codigop','$envio')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

if (!$resultado) {
    echo "Error al registrar los datos";
}
else {
    echo "Registro exitoso";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: y que error muestra

Comment: El if de las lineas 27 y 28 lo dice, aparece "Error al registrar los datos"

Comment: se guarda algo en tu base de datos?

Comment: Cuantos campos posee tu tabla productos? puede ser que estés dejando algún campo en blanco al insertar y lo configuraste para que no aceptara valores "null".

Comment: Alfredo Paz, No se guarda nada...

Comment: por qué `$Numero` con "N" mayúscula? Trata de no colocar las variables php con mayúscula

Comment: Huskie, la tabla productos posee 10 columnas

Comment: y si estan en ese orden las columnas?

Comment: justo después de `$Numero=$_POST["Numero"];` has un echo `$Numero; ` y dime si te devuelve algo por favor

Comment: Ponlo así y te dirá el error: `if (!$resultado) {
    echo "Error al registrar los datos: ".mysqli_error($conexion);` ... Cuando tengas el error [agrégalo a la pregunta editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/166516/edit).

Comment: revisa que estén llegando completo el POST

Comment: comprueba que los valores son del tipo de dato de cada campo de la tabla

Comment: Huskie, encontre un error, como decias, me faltaba un campo, lo agregue pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo. Hice lo del echo y me muestra el dato que ingrese en el formulario

Comment: por favor trata de no colocar las variables php con mayúscula. Corrige eso y prueba

Comment: Después de esta línea `$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);` ejecuta un `$var_dump($resultado);` y ve si te arroja datos por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Señores, enserio muchas gracias, fue un error super idiota de mi parte, era que estaba poniendo un numero que INT ya no soportaba. Gracias al usuario Huskie, pues me dio la funcion que me daba que era el error.
Disculpen por mi tonteria...
Un saludo